# io<s AVAssetTrack video-orientation

Tags: ios, video, orientation, avasset

I'm recording some video with a custom CaptureSessionManager and am rotating the preview layer according to the device orientation (otherwise, the preview layer is upside down either on landscape-left/right). This works so far. But...

When I try to play the video, I use the following code to determine the video's orientation:

```
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGSize size = [videoTrack naturalSize];
    CGAffineTransform txf = [videoTrack preferredTransform];

    if (size.width == txf.tx && size.height == txf.ty)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == 0)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == size.width)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
```

But the results are always the same, no matter whether it's left or right.

I used this code to get the output:

```
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGSize size = [videoTrack naturalSize];
    CGAffineTransform txf = [videoTrack preferredTransform];

    NSLog(@"Transformation a %f - b %f - c %f - d %f", txf.a, txf.b, txf.c, txf.d);
    NSLog(@"Transformation tx %f - ty %f", txf.tx, txf.ty);
    NSLog(@"Size width: %f - height: %f", size.width, size.height);
```

which results in:

```
Transformation a -1.000000 - b 0.000000 - c 0.000000 - d -1.000000
Transformation tx 1920.000000 - ty 1080.000000
Size width: 1920.000000 - height: 1080.000000
```

for both left and right orientation recordings.

Any ideas?

Comment: nice code snippet to determine video orientation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, stupid, stupid error…

I forgot to set the orientation on the output-file:

`self.recordingOrientation -> AVCaptureVideoOrientation` is stored when device is rotated or on startup of the recording.

AVCaptureConnection *CaptureConnection = [MovieFileOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

```
if ([CaptureConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
{
    [CaptureConnection setVideoOrientation:self.recordingOrientation];
}
```

Comment: here, what is `self. recordingOrientation`??
I have same problem

Comment: it's the orientation of the video AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight | AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft | AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortraitUpsideDown | AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait